# Is it possible to submit a PDF form in the Edge PDF Viewer?

Tags: pdf, submit, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

We have created a web application that needs to show fillable PDF forms in the browser.  The PDF forms include a Submit button. The user enters data on the PDF form and clicks the Submit button, which then posts the data in an HTTP message to a configured URL.  This functionality worked in IE 11 using the Adobe Reader Plugin.  Since the Adobe Reader Plugin is not supported in Edge, we are now considering our options for how we can get this functionality to work in Edge.

I have created a very simple PDF form (Acroform created in Adobe Acrobat Pro) with a submit button, but the Submit button does not seem to do anything when we display the PDF form in Microsoft Edge.  I have searched for information on whether other people have had the same problem but haven't found much. My guess is that Microsoft Edge does not support this Submit functionality yet, but I haven't found any specific documentation to confirm.  Does anybody know whether the Edge PDF Viewer supports this functionality in some shape or form, or whether they plan to support it in the future?

On some sites I see that the solution is to download the PDF form and use Adobe Reader. However, for business reasons this is not an option for us - we cannot be downloading the form to the user's desktop.

Note that we have found that the Submit button works to some extent in the Chrome PDF Viewer.  Specifically, when the user clicks Submit, the Chrome PDF Viewer does post the data to the URL but does not seem to process the response.  For business reasons, we would like to support Edge if at all possible.

If you have any information about Edge support for the PDF form submit button, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When your users see the PDF in the browser, where do you think that PDF is?

Comment: Is the PDF client side important? Why not have it as a regular web form. You could create a PDF later server side if the PDF is important.

Comment: I don't have Adobe Acrobat Pro so I made a pdf form with some online pdf editor. But the pdf form generated can't be submitted in neither Chrome nor Edge, it can only be submit using Adobe Acrobat Reader. It could be better if you can provide a test pdf file so that we can make tests in browsers.